# Handle error before subscribe to Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to correctly handle error in next function?

```
          this.userService.getUser(uid)
            .pipe(
              catchError(err => {
                this.router.navigate(['/sign-up']);
              })
            )
            .subscribe(user => {
              if (user) {
                this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.LoggedIn());
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
              }
            })
```

```
public getUser(uid: string): Observable<User> {
    const source = this.baseApolloService.query<{ uid: string }, User>(getUserQuery, (data) => data.getUser, { uid });
    return source;
  }
```

Currently, I'm getting an error:

> Provided 'undefined' where stream was expected

What I did wrong? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code inside getUser method in UserService

Comment: @BinaraThambugala added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `catchError` expects an `observable` stream and it says what should I return in case of an error to the `subscribe` non-error path. For your case, I would do this error handling in the `subscribe`.

```
this.userService.getUser(uid)
            .subscribe(user => {
              if (user) {
                this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.LoggedIn());
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
              }
            }, (error) => {
               console.log(error);
               this.router.navigate(['/sign-up']);
            })
```

Rxjs `catchError` requiring a stream and documentation: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch

======================== Edit ===========================
I see you want to handle the error before the subscribe, then yes, you have to provide a stream for the `subscribe` but the condition inside of the `if` won't run because we will return `null`.

Try:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
this.userService.getUser(uid)
            .pipe(
              catchError(err => {
                this.router.navigate(['/sign-up']);
                return of(null); // return null for the subscribe below
              })
            )
            .subscribe(user => {
              if (user) {
                this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.LoggedIn());
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
              }
            })
```

I think both ways are good.

Answer (score 1):

`catchError` has to return stream in return. This is to handle error and return the `default value`.

```
catchError((err) => {
  this.router.navigate(["/sign-up"]);
  // return something
  // of({data: "something"})
});
```

For your case u can catch error at end:

```
this.userService.getUser(uid).subscribe(
  (user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.LoggedIn());
      this.router.navigate(["/"]);
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.router.navigate(["/sign-up"]);
  }
);
```

**More:** https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError

Answer (score 0):

This will hep you.

```
 this.userService.getUser(uid)
   .pipe(catchError(err => {
       this.handleError(err);
       return of<any>({ isSuccess: false, error: err });
 }).subscribe(user => {
       //your code
   })
```

If an error occurs, then the catchError logic is going to kick in. The catchError operator is going to take the error and pass it to the error handling function.  The catchError is simply a function that takes in an input Observable, and outputs an Output Observable.That function is expected to return an Observable which is going to be a replacement Observable for the stream that just errored out. The error handling function is as below.

```
 private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): void {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        }
    }
```